# What can be the reason for getting different values for the same registry key?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I want to read the registry key **\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName**.

When I check the key in the registry editor, I'm getting the value "Window 10 Pro".
However, when I'm reading the same key in my c# application, the result is "Window 10 Enterprise"
Any ideas what the reason can be for this strange behaviour?

The OS is a Windows 10 64bit version, the application is targeted to .NET Framework 4.6.1, the platform for building in visual studio is 'Any CPU'.

The code snippet from my application:

```
registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", false);
if (registryKey != null)
{
    nameString = registryKey.GetValue("ProductName", "-Unknown-").ToString();
```

Comment: How're you accessing that info in C#?, the question needs a little more info, show us some code

Comment: I noticed this already and have added a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd first check to make sure those two things actually ran on the same computer.

Otherwise, there is one thing that can do this. HKLM\Software has an entry called `WOW6432Node`. The "WOW" here is for "Windows on Windows". It's used when older 32-bit processes access the registry to *redirect the query* into that section, similar to the `Program Files` vs `Program Files (x86)` folders. So a 32-bit process accessing here:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
```

will instead read from here:

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProductName
```

But again: for this particular key it would be very strange indeed for those two items to have different values.

Comment: It seams that's the reason.
In the WOW6432Node entry I find the values I'm getting in my application. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also have the same problem, great information on solving the question.